# Error during conversion of shapefile to MySQL using ogr2ogr

Tags: gdal, ogr, error, ogr2ogr, mysql

I have installed MS4W in Windows 7. I get an error when I try to convert a shapefile to MySQL database using GDAL/OGR `ogr2ogr`.

This is the command I'm trying:

`C:\ms4w\tools\gdal-ogr>ogr2ogr -f MySQL MySQL:banyuwangigis,user=root,password=
-lco GEOMETRY_NAME=layerkecamatan c:\ms4w\apps\banyuwangigis\petadasar\shp\admin
polygon.shp`

This is the resulting error:

`MySQL driver does not support data source creation.`

What have I missed?

Answer (score 1):

According to the OGR [MySQL driver doc](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_mysql.html):

> The MySQL driver does not support creation of new datasets (a database
>   within MySQL), but it does allow creation of new layers within an
>   existing database.

So, in your case, you have to [create the database](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-database.html) `banyuwangigis` first.